# How does one contact a moderator to get a question moved to a different forum

Tags: support, moderators

I currently have a question running on ME for educational math software.  It's been there several weeks with no satisfactory answers.  How do I get it moved to Software Review?

Comment: Can you not just post the same question there yourself?

Comment: I commented on you question some time ago saying 'If you really want to have the question moved you can "flag" with reason "other" and ask for this. It is certainly a valid way to proceed. However, I think to just ask it again elsewhere while putting links in both directions is also a good option in this case. (Personally I'd go for this.) What one should not do is to post on different sites at the same point in time (or almost the same).' It is now not clear to me if you had not noticed that comment or if it does not answer the question. Could you please clarifiy.

Comment: My bad.  I skimmed the comment, and missed the 'flag with reason'  Why is it better to repost with link?

Comment: Yes I could repost, but my understanding of SE is that the purpose is to consolidate answers, and comments in one spot to make the next person's quest easier.  Also the etiquette on proper time between reposting is not clear.

Comment: Migration is mainly for questions that are off-topic for this site. The click through goes: 'close' for reason 'off-topic' for particular reason 'belongs to another site [and not here]'. Your question is not off-topic here but to the contrary was well received. You are talking about making somebodies quest easier, but I doubt deleting the question here is doing that. Look how duplicates are handled. They are turned into a link but are still preserved as sign posts. Your question here could play a similar role.

Comment: For the timing. I think it makes sense to wait as long as one can assume with some confidence that hardly any regular user will see the question for the first time after that point in time (as everybody either already saw it or will also not in the future). I think this is a save assumption for your question.

Answer (score 1):

The way to contact moderators for migrating a question is to flag the question (use the button below the question) with reason 'other' and explain the request in the text-box.

If needed moderators can reply to the request when handling the flag (check you flagging history to see the reply) or also by others means.

Generally speaking, flagging and posting on meta are good ways to get in touch with moderators. Off-site communication via email is not as desirable as there is no shared infrastructure and the information thus would not be accessible to all the moderators and community managers.

However, just that a question does not receive an answer on this site and you want to ask it elsewhere in addition is not reason to migrate it away, which leads to deletion within some time on this site. Good on-topic questions should rather be preserved on the site. Another version of the question can still be posted on another site, giving links back-and-forth. While there can be considerable push-backs against cross-posts, this is restricted to (near) simultaneous postings. Asking with a reasonable delay is alright. In my mind a reasonable delay is one that allows to assume with some confidence that hardly any regular user will see the question for the first time after that point in time (as everybody either already saw it or will also not in the future); the specific timespan depends on the site and the context and might evolve over time, but I would say several days to a week is a reasonable delay (for this site, at the moment).

Comment: Posted in the interest of having an answer (for future references). The current issue seems resolved; the question was reposted as discussed in comments.